# Show Monthly Revenue By EmployeeID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a database with sale data for the past 5 years, 2012 - current.  I am in need of showing a breakdown by employeeID and the monthly sale amount.  I know this syntax will work, but it is going to be quite cumbersome to add a new case statement every time we roll into a new month.  Is there a quicker/more efficient way to accomplish this?

This is sample DDL (sample as it is only a very few rows)...

```
Declare @Monetary Table(empID varchar(10), empsaleamt float, empsaledate date)
Insert Into @Monetary (empID, empsaleamt, empsaledate) Values
('123abc', 100.00, '20160101'), ('123abc', 200.00, '20160101'), ('123abc', 300.00, '20160201')
,('456cde', 200.00, '20160101'), ('456cde', 100.00, '20160201'), ('456cde', 100.00, '20160301')

Select
empID
,Sum(case when (Year(empsaledate) = '2016' AND Month(empsaledate) = '01') Then empsaleamt Else 0 End) As Jan16Sales
,Sum(case when (Year(empsaledate) = '2016' AND Month(empsaledate) = '02') Then empsaleamt Else 0 End) As Feb16Sales
,Sum(case when (Year(empsaledate) = '2016' AND Month(empsaledate) = '03') Then empsaleamt Else 0 End) As Mar16Sales
FROM @Monetary
Group By empID
ORDER By empID ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

You could consider to use a [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) solution:

> ```
> Declare @Monetary Table(empID varchar(10), empsaleamt float, empsaledate date)
> Insert Into @Monetary (empID, empsaleamt, empsaledate) Values
> ('123abc', 100.00, '20160101'), 
> ('123abc', 200.00, '20160101'), 
> ('123abc', 300.00, '20160201'),
> ('456cde', 200.00, '20160101'), 
> ('456cde', 100.00, '20160201'), 
> ('456cde', 100.00, '20160301'),
> ('123abc', 100.00, '20170101'), 
> ('123abc', 200.00, '20170101'), 
> ('123abc', 300.00, '20170201'),
> ('456cde', 200.00, '20170101'), 
> ('456cde', 100.00, '20170201'), 
> ('456cde', 100.00, '20170301');
>
> SELECT ID, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
> FROM 
>     (SELECT CONCAT(empId,'-',CAST(YEAR(empsaledate) AS varchar(10))) as ID, 
>             month(empsaledate) AS months, empsaleamt
>      FROM   @monetary ) src
> PIVOT 
>     (SUM(empsaleamt) FOR months IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) pvt;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID          |   1 |   2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |   11 |   12
> :---------- | --: | --: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> 123abc-2016 | 300 | 300 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null
> 123abc-2017 | 300 | 300 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null
> 456cde-2016 | 200 | 100 |  100 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null
> 456cde-2017 | 200 | 100 |  100 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c62f42475aa2d43e0ae38bf9f8ddff56)*

Comment: Would I need an individual pivot for each year?

Comment: No, but then maybe you should use a dynamic query. PIVOT requires a well known column's name

Comment: the column names remain the same, just the dates range from 2015 to 2017 and will continue into 2018 etc

Comment: Or compose an ID as [EmpID] + [Year].

Comment: Excellent solution!  I will go that route, thank you!